# Details(examples) of "pseudo-definition", "pseudo-file", "sort_file" for mksquashfs?

Tags: debian, squashfs

[From debian stretch man page:](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/squashfs-tools/mksquashfs.1.en.html#Filesystem_filter_options)

```
Filesystem filter options
   -p PSEUDO_DEFINITION
       Add pseudo file definition.

   -pf PSEUDO_FILE
       Add list of pseudo file definitions.

   -sort SORT_FILE
       sort files according to priorities in SORT_FILE. One file or dir with priority per line. Priority -32768 to 32767, default priority 0.
```

But how to write `PSEUDO_DEFINITION`, `PSEUDO_FILE`, and `SORT_FILE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more information in the README that might be part of the distributed package, or can be seen [here](https://github.com/Othernet-Project/squashfs-tools/blob/master/README#L580) *3.8 Pseudo file support*.

For example,

```
-p 'mychardev c 666 root root 100 1'
```

creates a character device with major/minor 100/1.
Similarly, if you have a file `mylist` holding the lines

```
mydir         d 777 0 0
mydir/thedate f 776 0 0 date +'year is %Y'
```

then `-pf mylist` will create a directory and a file within it holding the result of doing the command `date +'year is %Y'` at the time `mksquashfs` was run.

The `-sort` option is not described further, but accepts filenames within the resulting filesystem, followed by a number, for example

```
b/c 500
b/d 700
```

where `b/c` and `b/d` are found in your squashfs. My version does not recognise names provided through the `-p` options, and indeed stops the above `date` example from working. If necessary you can split up the building of the filesystem into separate `mksquashfs` commands with different options, and each set of new files will be appended at the end.